# configuring nginx with agendav / troubles forwarding php params

Tags: php, nginx

i tried setting up agendav (a php web calendar client) with nginx. I managed to see the login prompt. Unfortunately i did not understand exactly what will happen when i try to login and iam not very familiar with nginx yet. Dealing with regex makes me insane as well and there is also no plenty documentation.

My php index file is located at /usr/share/agendav/web/public/index.php I'll access the application through the following url: https://server.com/public/index.php wich works just fine. After entering username and password i'll be forwarded to https://server.com/public/index.php/login. But this will give me a 404 error code.

i guess my try_files is wrong but i do not find out how to fix this.

here is the interesting part of my nginx server configuration:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name server.com;

        root /usr/share;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cacert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privkey.pem;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        fastcgi_param   HTTPS               on;
        fastcgi_param   HTTP_SCHEME         https;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                auth_basic      "Authorisation Required";
                auth_basic_user_file /usr/share/nginx/www/users;
        }

        location /public {
               root /usr/share/agendav/web/;
               index index.php;
               location ~ /public/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
                       root /usr/share/agendav/web/;
                       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               }
        }
```

could someone please guide me how to make this work?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that please ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URI `/public/index.php/login` is a PHP script with path info, which does not match your PHP regex location. You need to adjust the regular expression, extract the path info and execute the script.

There are a number of examples using `fastcgi_split_path_info` and `if` directives, but I prefer using `try_files` like this:

```
set $controller /public/index.php;

location /public {
    root /usr/share/agendav/web;
    index index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ $controller;

    location ~ ^(?<script>.*\.php)(?<pathinfo>.*)$ {
        try_files $script $controller;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $pathinfo;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) for more. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/) for a general source of `nginx` documentation.